# Which is the best file explorer or file commander

Tags: file, search, text

I need file explorer or file commander which search strings in more than one text file in the same time. Like FreeCommander but they doesn't search good enough. Which is free.

Comment: Unless you intend to write your own, this is off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

Try [grep](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep).